# Image is getting shrink-ed after refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In an employee detail page am showing a image of the employee in certain size , when the page is get refresh the size of the image getting shrink-ed.

```
     <Col xs="12" sm="2">
        <img
          src={this.state.image==='' ? loader : this.state.image}
          className="img-avatar avatar"
        />
     </Col>
```

In css ,

```
    .avatar{
  width: 135px;
  height: 135px;
  border: 0.18em solid #3f51b5;
}
```

state initialization and updation :

```
  this.state = { image: '' };

componentDidMount() {
const employees = this.props.employees;
let employee = {};
let employeeID = this.props.match.params.id;
employee = employees[employeeID];
setTimeout(() => {
  this.setState({
    image: employee.profilePicture
  });
}, 500);
```

}

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does it shrink in all breakpoints?

Comment: Can you show how you initialize and update the state?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure to load CSS file first. So image size always will be the same size.

**width: 135px;
height: 135px;**